# Custom Tag to use another JSPs in your JSP based on conditions

Tags: jstl, jsp-tags

I have a requirement where i need to include a JSP in some JSP, and the path of JSP which i need to include depends on some conditions.

I used getJspContext().include(), but it corrupted the future requests.

So i started using getJspBody().invoke(StringWriter writer).

The issue which i am facing is it will execute the JSP content passed in custom tag, which is something like:

```
<%@ include file="addressForm.jsp" %>
```

However i need to specify the the path of JSP in the TAG so that i can different paths based on different conditions.

I checked but didn't find a proper way to set the JSP body.

Please tell how can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

This is my preferred way to include JSP:

```
<c:import url="addressForm.jsp"/>
```

And you can make the url parameter dynamic (the stuff in the ${ ... } is a variable).

```
<c:import url="${path}/${form}.jsp"/>
```

So in this example, the ${path} is a variable that you can set and the same with ${form}.   If you want to play around with this type of include make sure you also include this at the top of your JSP page:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

There are tons of examples and tutorials about using JSTL and the "core" tag library.  Here's one:  http://www.javatpoint.com/jstl

Comment: But this will require me defining "path" for every JSP where i need to include JSP.

That's why i needed the custom tag, which will have the jspName as the parameter and the JSP Path will be calculated in the CustimTag.java.

Comment: You don't define "path", you calculate it and set it dynamically based on some conditions.  For example with a c:choose statement.   Apparently I don't understand your question, but with what you have described (again I am probably not understanding it correctly), a custom tag would be more complicated than necessary.